# Un-flattening a table

Tags: sql

I have a table that takes the following form:

```
person, date, food1, food2, food3
```

I would like to take this table and get a result that looks like this:

```
person, date, foodId
```

So for instance, if I had a row in my original table that looked like this:

```
Andy, 1/1/2012,false,true,true
```

I would get a result that looks like this

```
Andy, 1/1/2012, food2
Andy, 1/1/2012, food3
```

So far I have

```
SELECT person, date, 
(
    case 
        when food1 = true then 'food1'
        when food2 = true then 'food2'
        when food3 = true then 'food3'
    end
) as foodId
```

But this only grabs one result per source row when there can be up to 3 results per source row.  Any way I can fix my query to get 2 rows from my example instead of just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(SELECT person, date, 'food1' as foodId from table where food1 = true
UNION ALL
SELECT person, date, 'food2' as foodId from table where food2 = true
UNION ALL
SELECT person, date, 'food3' as foodId from table where food3 = true
) ORDER BY person
```

**EDIT** (in response to a comment)

If you need to put this into a temp table, change the query to this:

```
select person, date, FoodId
into #my_temp_table
from (
    SELECT person, date, 'food1' as foodId from table where food1 = true
    UNION ALL
    SELECT person, date, 'food2' as foodId from table where food2 = true
    UNION ALL
    SELECT person, date, 'food3' as foodId from table where food3 = true
) table_alias
```

Comment: How can I put this into a temp table?

Comment: @sooprise I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can UNPIVOT the data: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Setup:

```
create table diet(person varchar(10), entry datetime, food1 varchar(10), food2 varchar(10), food3 varchar(10))
insert into diet values('John', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Apple','Pizza','Cake');
```

Unpivot Query:

```
SELECT person, entry, meal, food
FROM 
   (SELECT person, entry, food1, food2, food3
   FROM diet) p
UNPIVOT
   (food FOR meal IN 
      (food1, food2, food3)
      )AS unpvt;
```

Output:

```
person  entry   meal    food
John    2012-02-08 14:42:22.940 food1   Apple
John    2012-02-08 14:42:22.940 food2   Pizza
John    2012-02-08 14:42:22.940 food3   Cake
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is with three queries:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (person, date, foodID) SELECT person, date, 'food1' FROM Table1 WHERE food1;
INSERT INTO Table2 (person, date, foodID) SELECT person, date, 'food2' FROM Table1 WHERE food2;
INSERT INTO Table2 (person, date, foodID) SELECT person, date, 'food3' FROM Table1 WHERE food3;
```

Comment: Agh, that's kind of ugly.  Hopefully there's a better way, but I'll start coding this up just in case there isn't.  Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like two other people are giving the same answer, I will go ahead and do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT person, date, 'food1' AS foodID FROM YourTable1 WHERE food1 = true
UNION ALL
SELECT person, date, 'food2' AS foodID FROM YourTable1 WHERE food2 = true
UNION ALL
SELECT person, date, 'food3' AS foodID FROM YourTable1 WHERE food3 = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that in SQL? Presentation should be done in, well, presentation layer, not data manipulation layer.

In addition to architectural "ugliness", you'll also incur some performance penalty: when returning the result of the query to the client, instead of transferring one row with simple Booleans, your DBMS now has to transfer up to 3 rows, with repeated `person` and `date`, plus `food` represented as string instead of Boolean.

---

OTOH, if you actually want to redesign your data model and need a way to transfer the data from the old model to the new, well that is a different matter...